# Rails Undefined Method 'model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activemodel

I have the following model:

```
class Contact
  attr_accessor :name, :emails, :message

  def initialize(attrs = {})
    attrs.each do |k, v|
      self.send "#{k}=", v
    end
  end

  def persisted?
    false
  end
end
```

I am calling to a contact form in my view like so:

```
<div class="email_form">
   <%= render 'form' %>
</div>
```

Here is the controller:

```
class ShareController < ApplicationController
  layout "marketing_2013"
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
    @contact = Contact.new
  end
end
```

Here is the Form:

```
<%= form_for(@contact) do |f| %>
    <%= f.label :name, "Your Name" %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
    <%= f.label :text, "Send to (separate emails with a comma)" %>
    <%= f.text_field :emails %>
    <%= f.label :message, "Email Text" %>
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

For some reason I keep getting this error:
`undefined method model_name for Contact:Class`

Any reason why what I have currently wouldn't work?

Comment: This has been answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823736/undefined-method-model-name-for-projectclass

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Besides the correct route in your config/routes.rb, you will also need these two instructions on your model:

```
include ActiveModel::Conversion
extend  ActiveModel::Naming
```

Take a look at this question: [form_for without ActiveRecord, form action not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577975/form-for-without-activerecord-form-action-not-updating).

For the `route` part of these answer, you could add this to your config/routes.rb:

```
resources :contacts, only: 'create'
```

This will generate de following route:

```
contacts POST /contacts(.:format)  contacts#create
```

Then you can use this action (contacts#create) to handle the form submission.

Comment: I was missing the the two instructions you listed. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add `include ActiveModel::Model` to your Contact file

Answer (score 0):

your route probably doesn't go where you think it's going and therefore @contact is probably nill

run "rake routes" and check the new path.. if you are using defaults, the route is

new_contact_path.. and the erb should be in file: app/views/contacts/new.html.erb

`def new
    @contact = Contact.new
  end`